# Reducing console output from GruntJS

Tags: gruntjs

I'm building my project with Grunt, using grunt-contrib-less, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-replace, and a few others. Currently, when I build, a ton of output flies through the command window, especially from grunt-replace as it runs on a lot of files.

What I would like is the equivalent of quiet mode in VS, where the only real output is whether the build succeeded, but verbose error information when errors occur.

I tried using grunt-verbosity and setting logs to hidden, but that seems to squash error output as well. I also tried setting `grunt.log.write = function(){}`, but that also causes errors to not be printed.

Has anyone dealt with a problem like this?